# IIS 7.5 WCF Version Registered

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5

How do I ensure that WCF 4.0 is the only version of WCF registered within IIS 7.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply by installing nothing but .NET 4.0 on that web server, and by making .NET 4.0 the default setting for your application pool(s) on that web server.

I don't think you can make sure to have only WCF 4.0 "registered" if you have multiple versions of .NET on that server box.